# If $X$ is separable then is the group of isometries on $X$ separable?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

I'm looking for the conditions on $X$ so that the isometry group of $X$ is separable.  We are taking the group to have the operation of composition and the topology of pointwise limits.

To be honest, I don't even know any isometries besides the identity function so I could possibly make due with some examples of isometries.

Any hints/answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a standard way to give the isometry group a topology? Suppose $X$ is a $\mathbb N$ with with the discrete metric. Then its isometry group is uncountable, and it's hard to imagine a natural topology for it that would make it separable.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something, but the concept of an "isometry" doesn't exist in a topological space; you need a metric for it to have any meaning. Indeed, choose two equivalent metrics that give rise to the same topology. Then isometries in one metric space need not be isometries in the other.

EDIT: Unless you are taking $X$ to be a metric space (on first reading, I thought you took $X$ to be a topological space but upon rereading, I see you left it ambiguous).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $X$ be a countably infinite space with the discrete metric. Then any permutation of $X$ is an isometry. There are uncountably many, and there are no nontrivial convergent sequences of isometries. For example of isometries, these abound, depending on your space.

So for $\mathbb{R}^2$ you can have translations and rotations around the origin and reflection about a line and compositions of these.